# Codenvy. "The system is out of resources. Please contact your system admin."

Tags: python, codenvy

[image]

Don't understand this error, while creating python slack.

Answer (score 0):

Someone seem to have had a similar question and got some help here:
https://groups.google.com/a/codenvy.com/forum/#!topic/codenvy/N1OE5BgfZNk

> "Can you run the following please?

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

> And then try creating a new workspace again."
>   "Did you run this command as a root? It should work.
>   As to why it happens, Swarm reserves resources for stopped containers as well and the current version of Codenvy does not delete them after a workspace is stopped. This is fixed in the new version."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening at beta.codenvy.com?  Or on your own downloaded Codenvy system?  You can also file an issue at https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues where support and engineers hang out.

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue happens when you are running your own private Codenvy system and the underlying hardware is out of memory / CPU to give to users. So while the user gets this message, its an indication that the system administrator needs to add additional physical nodes to the cluster. I am going to open an issue as I believe we have implemented capabilities to prevent new workspaces from being started for the user if the underlying system is out of resources.  So you may be running an old version - can you upgrade to 5.0.0-M4 please?